# Convert event Object to DependencyObject Windows Phone App C#

Tags: c#, .net, windows-phone-8

When my windows phone app loads I have a timer class that sets off an event every so often in the background.

What I want to happen is when the event is running a `ProgressIndicator` is shown at the top. However `SystemTray.SetProgressIndicator` requires a Dependency Object, which I don't have because I'm inside of a static. Is there any way I can convert the object sender to a Dependency Object? Is there a way I can generate a Dependency Object?

Below is the code:

```
    static public partial class TimerSync
    {
        static public void SetupTimer()
        {
            Timer.Interval = 15
            Timer.Tick += Timer_Tick;
            Timer.Start();        
        }

        static public void Timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var command = sender as DependencyObject;
            SystemTray.SetProgressIndicator(command, MyApp.Global.ProgressShow("Syncing, please wait..."));
            DoMyStuff();
            SystemTray.SetProgressIndicator(command, MyApp.Global.ProgressHide());
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you could acquire your current Page and use it as Dependency Object.

```
var frame = (Frame)Window.Current.Content;
var page = (Page)frame.Content;
```

Be carefull with that, you should check the values first.

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me. I already tried this with `var currentPage = ((App)Application.Current).RootFrame.Content as PhoneApplicationPage;` and basically it doesn't work. I'm not 100% sure of the logic behind why, but I believe its because this is independent of what is happening on the page and it is not being called by a postback on the page itself.